# My blog suddenly can't find my stylesheet?

Tags: themes, customization, errors, css

I created a custom theme awhile back, and everything has worked fine up until now. All of a sudden, my theme was reverted back to the default twenty eleven theme because apparently my custom theme is missing it's stylesheet, but the stylesheet is clearly there. I link to it correctly and everything. I don't understand why all of a sudden it would stop working? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed anything in the stylesheet? WordPress looks for the header of that file to be in a specific format. http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet

You could also check that all folders/filenames are consistent. Hopes this helps in some way - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this old question, as it can be useful to a lot of beginners who are facing the same issue. 
Follow these steps:

1. Find and open the folder of the theme that you have on your PC
2. You should see all the files of the theme there. If not, the theme
   might be located in a sub-directory. So, you have to check the
   sub-directories to get it.
3. After finding, zip and upload the theme folder via WordPress. You
   can also upload the the unzipped folder via FTP.

Now, you will find that the missing stylesheet issue has been fixed.